# print differences of file1 to file2 without deleting anything from file2

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm creating a script that searches IPs from a.csv log file against pre-defined blacked IP lists.

It first imports the log file, then parses IPs from it, then searches the parsed IPs against pre-defined blacked IP list, finally it needs to ask user (if any result found) to save the results to the original log file that was imported.

File 1 is a example of IP-output.csv in the code.

File 2 is a example of $filename in the code (original imported .csv).

File 1:

```
107.147.166.60 ,SUSPICIOUS IP
107.147.167.26 ,SUSPICIOUS IP
108.48.185.186 ,SUSPICIOUS IP
108.51.114.130 ,SUSPICIOUS IP
142.255.102.68 ,SUSPICIOUS IP
```

File 2:

```
outlook.office365.com ,174.203.0.118 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,107.147.166.60 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,107.147.167.26 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,174.205.17.24 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,108.48.185.186 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,174.226.15.21 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,108.51.114.130 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,67.180.23.93 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,142.255.102.68 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,164.106.75.235 ,UserLoginFailed
```

I wanna change File 2 to this:

```
outlook.office365.com ,174.203.0.118 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,107.147.166.60 ,UserLoginFailed ,SUSPICIOUS IP
outlook.office365.com ,107.147.167.26 ,UserLoginFailed ,SUSPICIOUS IP
outlook.office365.com ,174.205.17.24 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,108.48.185.186 ,UserLoginFailed ,SUSPICIOUS IP
outlook.office365.com ,174.226.15.21 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,108.51.114.130 ,UserLoginFailed ,SUSPICIOUS IP
outlook.office365.com ,67.180.23.93 ,UserLoginFailed
outlook.office365.com ,142.255.102.68 ,UserLoginFailed ,SUSPICIOUS IP
outlook.office365.com ,164.106.75.235 ,UserLoginFailed
```

This is the script I created:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# IP Blacklist Checker
#Import .csv (File within working directory)
echo "Please import a .csv log file to parse/search the IP(s) and UserAgents: "
read filename
#Parsing IPs from .csv log file
echo "Parsing IP(s) from imported log file..."
grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' $filename | sort | uniq > IP-list.txt
echo 'Done'
awk 'END {print NR,"IP(s) Found in imported log file"}' IP-list.txt
echo 'IPs found in imported log file:'
cat IP-list.txt
#searches parsed ip's against blacked ip lists
echo 'Searching parsed IP(s) from pre-defined Blacked IP List Databases...'
fgrep -w -f "IP-list.txt" "IPlist.txt" > IP-output.txt
awk 'END {print NR,"IP(s) Found Blacked IP List Databases"}' IP-output.txt
echo 'Suspicious IPs found in Blacked IP List Databases:'
cat IP-output.txt
while true; do
read -p "Do you want to add results to log file?" yn
case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) grep -Ff IP-output.txt $filename | sed 's/$/ ,SUSPICIOUS IP/' > IP-output.csv && awk 'FNR==NR {m[$1]=$0; next} {for (i in m) {match($0,i); val=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); if (val) {sub(val, m[i]); print; next}};} 1' IP-output.csv $filename > $filename; break;;
    [Nn]* ) break;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
esac
done
echo "Finished searching parsed IP(s) from pre-defined Blacked IP List Databases."
rm IP-list.txt IP-output.csv IP-output.txt
```

The log file I'm importing is really long with 15-20 columns, and the IPlist.txt (blacked IPs) has over 15000 IPs in it. After saving the results to the same log file, .csv file gets empty, and if I save it under a different name, all the columns go out of order, and the ", SUSPICIOUS IP" column appears next to the IP column, I need it instead to be at the last column (end of the line).

I also don't know how to prompt to save for a file only if anything was found, if not only prompt nothing found!

The results i'm getting:

```
 outlook.office365.com ,174.203.0.118 ,UserLoginFailed
 outlook.office365.com ,107.147.166.60 ,SUSPICIOUS IP ,UserLoginFailed
 outlook.office365.com ,107.147.167.26 ,SUSPICIOUS IP ,UserLoginFailed
 outlook.office365.com ,174.205.17.24 ,UserLoginFailed
 outlook.office365.com ,108.48.185.186 ,SUSPICIOUS IP ,UserLoginFailed
 outlook.office365.com ,174.226.15.21 ,UserLoginFailed
 outlook.office365.com ,108.51.114.130 ,SUSPICIOUS IP ,UserLoginFailed
 outlook.office365.com ,67.180.23.93 ,UserLoginFailed
 outlook.office365.com ,142.255.102.68 ,SUSPICIOUS IP ,UserLoginFailed
 outlook.office365.com ,164.106.75.235 ,UserLoginFailed
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Are the commas intentionally on the wrong side?

Comment: commas indicate a separate column in .csv file. so if you open a .csv file in text editor, each comma represents a column

Comment: @bruh321 Please hit the green ✓ if the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { m[$1]=$0; next; } { for (i in m) { idx = index($0, i); if (idx > 0) { print substr($0, 1, idx-1) m[i]; next; } } } 1' file1.txt file2.txt > newfile2.txt
```

It basically processes `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` sequentially. `FNR==NR` is true for all lines from the first file, where a map `m` is build up with replacement patterns (everything before the first space is mapped to the entire line). For the second file, each line will be checked for a match in `m`. If there's a match (using`index()`), the script prints everything before the match and then the value from `m`. Oh, and the final `1` will print non-matching lines from file2.

Comment: It's nice that this answer works for the OP however, I would have upvoted it had it included an explanation of what it's doing.

Comment: I have to admit I was hoping for a more in depth explanation, not just a synopsis. My bad for not being more explicit in my first comment however, I'll +1 anyway.  I do want to say that I believe users learn so much more from the code of answer such as this when it includes a somewhat detailed mechanical breakdown, so to speak, then just a synopsis.

Comment: You're calling the wrong function the wrong way. `match()` is for regexps, not strings, so every `.` in the IP address from file1 will be treated as an "any character" wildcard and you're doing partial matching so IP addresses from file1 that occur in parts of IP addresses from file2 will falsely be treated as a match. This is a case where the posted script could produce the expected output from the given sample input but will fail in general given different input. But of course the OP just accepted the first answer he got so - good luck with that!

Comment: @EdMorton True. Usually I give better answers which I'm afraid often literally noone ever reads. Chances were high that this would be the case here as well when you look at the question. I just didn't want to put too much efford here and merely help the OP quickly. Anyways. I replaced the logic with a better one.

Comment: @EdMorton Downvote? Really? Didn't you notice the edit according to your comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. See the comment by @jww under the question? Every time he leaves that comment he also downvotes every answer because he didn't like the question. He's famous for it and sometimes he does it without leaving a comment. I and others when we see that comment upvote every answer to compensate (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018840/1745001 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862398/remove-a-block-of-code#comment90690416_51862398) as I'm doing for yours now. It's ridiculous but the moderators say he's not violating any rules so we're stuck with it.

Comment: FYI I just got jww-ed myself at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52012286/1745001, this time without a comment but the MO is unmistakable. He's a pesky little rascal :-). Doesn't know the first thing about shell or it's utilities and so, thankfully, never provides an answer about shell or it's utilities, and yet he runs around downvoting everyone. Quite a contributor!

Comment: @EdMorton http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/890812 :-) Have a counter+1.

Comment: @EdMorton I didn't know about jww until recently when it was pointed out to me by a kind user explaining a downvote I received. I am on board with "upvote to compensate" (unless, of course, the answer is really bad) ... so here guys, take +1 :)

Comment: @EdMorton, I wasn't aware of this, but now that you've pointed it out, I remember I got jww-ed too! That pesky rascal..